# Setting multiple instances on multiple servers of Memcached

Tags: caching, memcached, administration

While reading the documentation on Memcached, I got the impression that one can setup 
memcached across multiple servers thus creating a cluster. The question that naturally comes up, is the exact procedure of doing this.

I think that if such a feature exists is not well documented and the Memcached Wiki needs this addition. I found somewhere that you must include in the configuration files, the IP list of all the servers but is this enough? If someone could point me to a link or something outlining this procedure I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install it, run it, point all your clients to it the same way.  Did you try this?

Comment: Nope but I cannot understand how this happens... I suppose the hashing algorithm also assigns the key-value to a specific server? 

This does seem a bit awkward for the client. For example, what if the last server in the cluster has still some memory left, the client will attempt to insert the entry on every server before the available one?

Comment: The client will only interact with the correct server for the key.  If you have two servers, statistically, half of your data goes to each.